# How to Load data infile in MySQL avoiding records with 5 minutes of difference of the same client? (I can do it on excel easily)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert data on MySQL 8.0 that has 4 columns:

```
CLIENT_NUMBER VARCHAR(8)|SUBACCOUNT VARCHAR(2)|
DATE(DDMMYYYY)(VARCHAR(8))|TIME (HHMMSS)(VARCHAR(6))
```

Example of txt file to be inserted:

```
46851254|1|27122021|12:34:45 (this row has to be inserted)
46851254|1|27122021|12:36:45 (this row has to be ignored because 120 seconds of difference)
46851254|3|27122021|12:38:45 (this row has to be inserted)
46851254|3|27122021|12:43:46 (this row has to be inserted because more than 500 seconds passed)
46851254|3|27122021|12:44:45 (this row has to be ignored because 59 seconds of difference)
```

Clean txt file:

```
46851254|1|27122021|12:34:45 
46851254|1|27122021|12:36:45
46851254|3|27122021|12:38:45
46851254|4|27122021|12:39:45
46851254|3|27122021|12:41:45
```

I need to avoid inserting registers on a table that has 5 minutes of difference of the same client and same sub_account. I can edit the table as I want.

I can't do because it doesn't exist something as

```
LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE INTO TABLE transactions 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4) set client_number=@col1,
subaccount=@col2
date=@col3,
time=@col4 WHERE (DONT INSERT IF PREVIOUS row has same client and subaccount and difference time is less than 300 seconds )
;
```

Or maybe it does exist and I don't know it.

The table has not a primary key on any of the columns, the columns are only indexed for doing searchs faster.

At first I was thinking in convert date+time to Epoch and see if difference is less than 300, but I only know doing this with Excel. There I import the rows and do a function that says: "If ( (A2=A1) AND (B2<500))"DUPLICATED RECORD" ELSE "CORRECT RECORD"
Where I previously make the rows:
A: CONCAT(CLIENT_NUMBER AND SUBACCOUNT)
B: (DATE|TIME - 1/1/1970 00:00:00)*86400.
And then I import the "Row number" and then that rows numbers are my select * from where "there are not registers with 5 minutes difference.

If you could help me making the logic form I appreciate. I would like that the verification could be done while its doing the load data infile but I don't have any problem if first I have to insert the original rows and then process them and extract the "not duplicated ones".

Comment: What server-side programming language you are using ? php?

Comment: i would suggest you to use a programming language to create a clean file from the raw one. You just have to `openFile(), foreach(line) { compare and decide whether to keep }, create a new file` Then use the new file for `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: @IndraKumarS I'm just using MySQL Workbench. But I will mount the finish project on PHP 7 Laravel 8

Comment: then create a clean file using php as i suggested

Comment: @IndraKumarS You are right. I have to do it comparing lines using divide & conquer method. I'm using epoch time to compare the time difference in 500 seconds and writing the code to do it automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done by simply a "SQL line". It takes several process to the information, and it must be done with "Divide & Conquer".

1. Take the file ordered by `Client number, Subaccount number,epoch(date&time)`.
2. Search line by line if the previous line matches:

- Clientnumber of line n||subaccount of line n equals to
  Clientnumber of line n+1||subaccount of line n+1
- (epoch time of line n+1 - epoch time of line n) < 501

All that n lines that matches must have an row_id.

Then you select/mark the lines that applies to the two matches and insert them in a table.

You can run:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET duplicated_lines = 1 
WHERE row_id IN (SELECT row_id 
                 FROM table2)
```

Finally you can just run the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE duplicated = 0
```

You have all the data with one column that identifies if the register is duplicated or not.